# How can I access buffer variables from BufUnload/BufDelete?

Tags: buffers, autocmd, variables

vimdoc says:

```
BufUnload
Before unloading a buffer.  
...
NOTE: When this autocommand is executed, the
current buffer "%" may be different from the
buffer being unloaded "<afile>".
Don't change to another buffer or window, it
will cause problems!
```

If the current buffer isn't the deleted/unloaded buffer, then can I access b: variables? I have a buffer that has a temp file and if the buffer goes away, I want to clean up the temp file.

Example:

```
let b:example_tempfile = tempname()
augroup example
    au!
    au BufUnload <buffer> call delete(b:example_tempfile)
augroup END
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [:h <afile>](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Cafile%3E) to get unloading buffer name, use [:h getbufvar()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getbufvar%28%29) to get buffer local variable.

```
let b:example_tempfile = tempname()
augroup example
    au!
    au BufUnload <buffer> echom getbufvar( expand('<afile>'), 'example_tempfile' )
augroup END
bunload %

--------------------------------
/tmp/vovl8Be/48
```